# Using OpenTelemetry and JaegerUI with SpringBoot 2.5

Tags: spring-boot, monitoring, spring-cloud-sleuth, open-telemetry, jaeger

I'm trying to build a monitoring system for a Springboot application. I need to send some metrics to an OpenTelemetry collector and then to Jaeger.

I'm setting up Jaeger and OpenTelemetry via docker compose, these are my docker-compose.yml and otel-collector-config.yml

```
    version: "3.3"

    services:

       otel-collector:
        image: otel/opentelemetry-collector:latest
        command: [ "--config=/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml" ]
        volumes:
          - ./otel-collector-config.yaml:/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml:Z
        ports:
          - "13133:13133" # Health_check extension
          - "4317:4317"   # OTLP gRPC receiver
        depends_on:
          - jaeger-all-in-one

      jaeger-all-in-one:
        image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
        container_name: jaeger-all-in-one
       ports:
          - "16686:16686"
          - "14268:14268"
          - "14250:14250"
```

```
receivers:
      otlp:
        protocols:
          grpc:
            endpoint: otel-collector:4317

    exporters:
      jaeger:
        endpoint: jaeger-all-in-one:14250
        tls:
          insecure: true

    processors:
      batch:

    extensions:
      health_check:

    service:
      extensions: [health_check]
      pipelines:
       traces:
          receivers: [otlp]
          processors: [batch]
          exporters: [jaeger]
```

Also, these are my pom.xml dependecies:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-brave</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp-trace</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>1.42.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And i put in application.properties:

```
    spring.application.name = myName
    sleuth.enabled= true
    sleuth.otel.exporter.otlp.endpoint= http://localhost:4317
```

If I try to start the application I see that tracing is active and traceId and span are logged, but Jaeger does not receive anything, and the service is not even displayed.
I'm running out of ideas...